# Google Search Console API - Domain Wide Delegation - Returning no results

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-search-console, google-api-python-client

I setup (are at least attempted to) a domain-wide delegation for our Google apps domain for integration with a python script. In particular, I am currently trying to interact with the Search Console API.

Here is what I have done:

1. Setup service account
2. Enabled domain wide delegation
3. Added `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly` to the Google Admin console for the Authorized API client list.
4. Setup a simple script based off the one provided by Google

Here is my `test.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build


scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
    ]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/path/to/my/key.json', scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('me@mydomain.com')

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

webmasters_service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http_auth)

site_list = webmasters_service.sites().list().execute()

print site_list
```

The result:

```
{}
```

Bummer.

I know that this is incorrect because when I use [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/webmasters.sites.list) and authorize `me@mydomain.com` I see the full list of my sites in Search Console. Something is broken, and I am not sure where the problem is.

Any thoughts on steps that I missed in the process? Everything seems to authenticate. I do not get a `403`.

Scratching my head.

Comment: Thanks - this was first example i found of using a service account json (i already had one) file for webmasters and worked for me. Saved me a few hours i'd say :)

Comment: @andrewm4894 awesome. Glad this was of help to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not 100% sure what I did, or how I fixed it.

I was playing around with the permissions in the Admin console API client access utility with having and not having a trailing `/`. In the end, I changed my scope from `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters` and it worked!

I have not yet gone back to play with the readonly scope, partially because I do want my program to have write access. I was only using the readonly for test purpose.